# how to detect first time app launch after update from app store ,iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I need to do something only after when the application update from appstore.
I do it with NSUserDefaults but it's not good for me because it works only after the first update.

help

thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can compare the current version with the old version as follow:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Version %@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]];
```

And with an `if statement` for the current version that you know it 1.1, 2.0 .... etc, you can handle it.

Comment: I don't understand how this would work – wouldn't CFBundleShortVersionString just return the current version of the app? Wouldn't we need to know the version of the app the previous time the app was opened?

Comment: @Mutawe how do i compare the versions ?

Comment: if([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Version %@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]] isEqualToString:@"1.1") // Do something

Comment: I join @rob's question. I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: This is not the answer as it detects the version and runs code for it where as he asked to only execute the code on the first launch not every launch. Downvoted

Answer (score 10):

The [MTMigration](https://github.com/mysterioustrousers/MTMigration) project (MIT license) does exactly what you want:

> Manages blocks of code that only need to run once on version updates
>   in iOS apps. This could be anything from data normalization routines,
>   "What's New In This Version" screens, or bug fixes.

An example of its use:

```
[MTMigration migrateToVersion:@"0.9" block:^{
    // Some 0.9 stuff
}];

[MTMigration migrateToVersion:@"1.0" block:^{
    // Some 1.0 stuff
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Version %@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]]isEqualToString:@"Version 1.0"])
{
// run your code here
}
```